Is there a way to populate Array() in VBA from a dynamic string?
The purpose of the VBA is to look at what has been picked in a Pivot Table filter and use this to set the Filter on a different Pivot Table.
So, when the user uses "PivotTable1" and picks one, multiple, or all values in the Filter, the VBA will then automatically update the Filter selection in "PivotTable2" to match what was picked in the Filter for "PivotTable1".
This is my attempt so far, but I can't quite get the myArray right. If I manually input the myArray values then it works perfectly, but when I try to make myArray the results of the For Each Loop, it fails ("Unable to get the PivotItems property of the PivotField Class"). Even though the Debug.print MS looks exactly the same as the manually input the myArray values.
How can I get the results of MS into the MyArray?
Sub FilterPivotTables()

Dim pi As PivotItem
Dim pi_name(1024) As String
Dim MS As String

For Each pi In ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Area").PivotItems
If pi.Visible = False Then
    pi_name(i) = pi.value
        If MS = "" Then
        MS = """" & pi_name(i) & """"
        Else
        MS = MS & ", " & """" & pi_name(i) & """"
        End If
    i = i + 1
End If
Next pi

Debug.Print MS
'The below is what the Debug.Print MS shows:
'    "Red Zone", "Blue Zone"

Dim myArray() As Variant
'myArray = Array("" & MS & "")
myArray = Array("Red Zone", "Blue Zone")

Dim pf As PivotField
    Set pf = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Area")
    With pf
        .ClearManualFilter
        .EnableMultiplePageItems = True
            For i = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
                .PivotItems(myArray(i)).Visible = False
            Next i
    End With

End Sub


looks like MS is comma separated list? cant you just use the Split() function to split MS into an array?

Thank you for your help. Please can you copy my code into an "Answer" and change the bits you're referencing, as I'm not quite following.
